# How to remove unwanted characters in JSON String array format PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I clean Dirty JSON String format ?

For Example from this String

```
{"AS_applicant_Data__c":"{\\\"Full Name\u00a0\\\":\\\"asdffas\\\"}"}
```

to this format

```
{"AS_applicant_Data__c":"{"Full Name":"asdffas"}"}
```

Comment: You could use substr_replace? http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

Comment: I would have tried `stripslashes`, but you have `\u00a0` in the original string. Where did you get this string?

Comment: its from json object that has spaces (original object{"Full Name ":"asdffas"}).. then when I convert it to json string .. the white spaces turns into unwanted characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_replace` to remove all occurrences of `\` and `u00a0` from your json string, like this:

```
echo str_replace('u00a0', '', str_replace('\\', '', $json_string));
```

Output:

```
AS_applicant_Data__c":"{"Full Name":"asdffas"}"}
```